# pandas iterate over 3 data frames element wise into a function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i wrote :

```
def revertcheck(basevalue,first,second):
    if basevalue==1:
        return 0 
    elif basevalue > first and first > second:
        return -abs(first-second)
    elif basevalue < first and first < second:
        return -abs(first-second)
    else:
        return abs(first-second)
```

and now I have 3 same sized correlation matrices of the type

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I want to iterate over every element, and feed all those 3 values into my function at a time. Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

```
AAPL    AMZN    BAC GE  GM  GOOG    GS  SNP XOM
AAPL    1.000000    0.567053    0.410656    0.232328    0.562110    0.616592    0.800797    -0.139989   0.147852
AMZN    0.567053    1.000000    -0.012830   0.071066    0.271695    0.715317    0.146355    -0.861710   -0.015936
BAC 0.410656    -0.012830   1.000000    0.953016    0.958784    0.680979    0.843638    0.466912    0.942582
GE  0.232328    0.071066    0.953016    1.000000    0.935008    0.741110    0.667574    0.308813    0.995237
GM  0.562110    0.271695    0.958784    0.935008    1.000000    0.857678    0.857719    0.206432    0.899904
GOOG    0.616592    0.715317    0.680979    0.741110    0.857678    1.000000    0.632255    -0.326059   0.675568
GS  0.800797    0.146355    0.843638    0.667574    0.857719    0.632255    1.000000    0.373738    0.623147
SNP -0.139989   -0.861710   0.466912    0.308813    0.206432    -0.326059   0.373738    1.000000    0.369004
XOM 0.147852    -0.015936   0.942582    0.995237    0.899904    0.675568    0.623147    0.369004    1.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume `basevalue`, `first` and `second` are your three dataframes of exactly the same size and structure, then you can do what you want in a vectorised manner:

```
output = abs(first - second)
output = output.mask(basevalue == 1, 0)
output = output.mask((basevalue > first) & (first > second), -abs(first - second))
output = output.mask((basevalue < first) & (first < second), -abs(first - second))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I must have explained it poorly. My correlation matrices are in a list of matrices, the function posted above needs 3 integers that i want to get from those matrices, element by element

Comment: That's alright. You can extract those three matrices from the list to `basevalue`, `first` and `second` by doing  e.g. `basevalue, first, second = list_of_matrices` and then perform the above.

Comment: I am completely lost. I have my function( it has 3 inputs). Now i want to iterate over every element of my 3 correlations matrices and feed it into that function :(

Comment: The point I'm trying to make in my answer is that instead of iterating over each element of your data frames you can achieve what you want by running those four lines I posted.

Comment: TL;DR unpack your list of dataframes by doing `basevalue, first, second = list_of_dataframes` and run the four lines from my answer. `output` should be what you need.